# change value based on nested array value

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I got a below object from the API

```js
let response = {
    "id": 301344576,
    "quantity": 92,
    "unlimited": false,
    "inStock": true,
    "name": "Virgin Coconut Oil",
    "price": 328.47,
    "isShippingRequired": true,
    "weight": 0.5,
    "url": "https://subhikshaf2c.company.site/Virgin-Coconut-Oil-p301344576",
    "options": [
        {
            "type": "SELECT",
            "name": "Weight",
            "nameTranslated": {
                "en": "Weight"
            },
            "choices": [
                {
                    "text": "500 gm",
                    "textTranslated": {
                        "en": "500 gm"
                    },
                    "priceModifier": 0,
                    "priceModifierType": "ABSOLUTE"
                },
                {
                    "text": "1 kg",
                    "textTranslated": {
                        "en": "1 kg"
                    },
                    "priceModifier": 317.03,
                    "priceModifierType": "ABSOLUTE"
                }
            ],
            "defaultChoice": 0,
            "required": false
        }
    ],
    "combinations": [
        {
            "id": 161026822,
            "combinationNumber": 1,
            "options": [
                {
                    "name": "Weight",
                    "nameTranslated": {
                        "en": "Weight"
                    },
                    "value": "1 kg",
                    "valueTranslated": {
                        "en": "1 kg"
                    }
                }
            ],
            "sku": "OL002-001592-1kg",
            "quantity": 36,
            "inStock": true,
            "unlimited": false,
            "weight": 1,
            "warningLimit": 20,
            "attributes": [],
            "defaultDisplayedPrice": 677.78,
            "defaultDisplayedPriceFormatted": "₹677.78"
        }
    ]
}
```

and the weight info of this. Suppose i got `1KG` so i'm creating JSON like

```
  {
            "Id":301344576,
            "weight":"1 kg",
            "quantity":1
        }
```

In another page again I'm calling the same API and need to create json format like

```
[
  {
   
    "stock": 92,
    "quantity": 1,
    "productId": 301344576,
    "basePrice": 328.47,
    "productPrice": 344.89,
    "weight": "500 gm",
    "productName": "Virgin Coconut Oil",
   
  }
]
```

The problem is if the `weight: '1KG'` i need to look into the `combinations` and need to update the quantity. So my json will become like

```
   {
   
    "stock": 36,
    "quantity": 1,
    "productId": 301344576,
    "basePrice": 645.5,
    "productPrice": 344.89,
    "weight": "1 kg",
    "productName": "Virgin Coconut Oil",
    
}
```

for the `basePrice`, I'm doing `price+priceModifier` value of selected weight from the options.

How can i achieve the desired result.

Comment: the context isn't clear... Also I think there is some missing data ? or wrong information...

Comment: Thanks !!! I Solved the issue.